# fopen and fopen_s seem to be crashing on long file names

Tags: c, exception, fopen

I am using visual studio 2013 to build a c application

The code looks like this -

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char *InFilename = NULL;
    char *OutFilename = NULL;
    int ff_count; // counts the number of successive 0xff's read from the file buffer
    int fpga_end, nios_start, nios_end; // used to report the size of each region
    int file_length, file_index, temp_length, new_file_length;
    int root_length;
    int result;

    FILE *infile = NULL;
    FILE *outfile = NULL;

    printf("Start JIC 2 rbf\r\n");

    if ((argc != 2))
    {
        printf("\r\n\r\nV1.2 - Usage: <jic2rbf> <name of jicfile> \r\n");
        printf("\r\n This program strips out the header info at the top of the file\r\n");
        printf("\r\n  and most of the ff's at the bottom.  \r\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //
    // Extract the name of the input file up to the '.' and use it to create the output file name with a .rbf extension.
    //

    InFilename = argv[1];
    root_length = strcspn(InFilename,".");

    printf("Root len = %d\r\n",root_length);

    OutFilename = (char *)malloc(root_length+EXT_LENGTH);
    memcpy(OutFilename,InFilename,root_length);
    OutFilename[root_length] = 0;
    strcat(OutFilename,".rbf");

    printf("In file to be used %s\r\n", InFilename);
    printf("Out file to be used %s\r\n", OutFilename);

    result = fopen_s(&outfile, OutFilename, "wb");
    if (result)
    {
        printf("Cannot open this file %s\r\n - 0x%x", OutFilename, result);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Open In - %d\r\n",result);
```

If I call this executable from a dos command line with -

```
E:/projects/Q4300_Hdcp/q_series_hdcp_base/fpga/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_singleHID/par/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_singleHID/output_files/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_singleHID_elf.jic
```

The entire application works

If I call the application with the following command line -

```
E:/projects/Q4300_Hdcp/q_series_hdcp_base/fpga/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_fpga/par/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_fpga/output_files/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_fpga_elf.jic
```

I do not see the `printf("Open In - %d\r\n",result);` output.  The application just seems to crash.
I thought it might be some sort of buffer overflow in the file name but the shorter file name works.....  If I `cd` to the directory with the file and call with the command line `q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_fpga_elf.jic` that works.
If I dir the file - `E:/projects/Q4300_Hdcp/q_series_hdcp_base/fpga/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_fpga/par/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_fpga/output_files/q_series_hdcp_tx_dual_fpga_elf.jic` 
I see the file.......

I do not know how to catch the exception or what else to pursue to resolve this, any ideas would be great.
Thanks,
Martin

Comment: why use `memcpy` to copy strings? can't you use `strcpy` instead? also, your malloc needs to allocate an extra character for the null terminator.

Comment: `EXT_LENGTH` is not declared/defined any place.  Its value is important.

Comment: @bruceg OP is not trying to copy a _string_, but a portion of one, hence the reasonable use of `memcpy()`.

Comment: The posted code fails to cleanly compile.  Amongst many other problems,  it is missing the necessary `#include` statements.

Comment: never access beyong `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user

Comment: In C, when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value.  The returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain. 2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: what is `EXT_LENGTH`?  Note: EXT_LENGTH, in the current scenario, needs to be at least 5

Comment: Voting to close as 'off topic' as this is a run time problem and the posted code is just a fragment so the problem cannot be reproduced

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line:

```
OutFilename = (char *)malloc(root_length+EXT_LENGTH);
```

to this:

```
OutFilename = malloc(1 + root_length + EXT_LENGTH);
```

to allocate space for the null terminator.  Also, no need to cast malloc's return value.

Comment: Also make sure EXT_LENGTH is 4, since you are assuming it is the length of ".rbf"

Comment: Brilliant, thanks ---- I have been looking at this for a while but forgot to go back to the beginning of the program since that usually worked, lol.  The fix was the adding 1 to the malloc......, thank you

Answer (score 0):

DOS has some severe limits on command line length

so when the command line is too long, problems such as you are experience will occur.

Did you really mean that your using Visual Studio and Windows?

Many of the limitations of DOS have been carried forward into Windows and Visual Studio